# How is /proc/self implemented in Linux?

Tags: process, proc

I was tinkering around with the `/proc` filesystem in Linux, and I came across `/proc/self`, which is a symbolic link to the process directory of the current process. I would like to know how it is implemented. One solution would be to change that symlink on *every context switch*, but that's obviously very expensive as it involves a disk access.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.9/fs/proc/base.c#L2482 is the current implementation.

The `proc` filesystem is entirely virtual, and is implemented so the internal VFS `readlink` delegates to the right place for special symlinks.  So, it calculates what `self` points to when it is read / traversed, not every context switch.

Answer (score 13):

Files in `/proc` are not stored on a disk, they are generated on the fly by the kernel. See [What happens when I open and read from /proc?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8274/what-happens-when-i-open-and-read-from-proc)

If you're programmatically inclined, you can read the implementation of `/proc` in the [kernel source code](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/fs/proc). The contents of the [`/proc/self`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.11/fs/proc/base.c#L2518) symbolic link is generated by a [function](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.11/fs/proc/base.c#L2482) that fills a buffer with the pid of the calling process.